# Problem on Bounded Variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

Assume $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$. Show that there is a sequence of partitions $\{P_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ for which the sequence $\{TV(f,P_n)\}$is increasing and converges to $TV(f)$? 
Remark:-$TV(f)$ stand for total variation .

Comment: This is just the definition of the supremum.

Comment: @TooOldForMath thanks for you comment it was useful .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition
$$
\mathrm{TV}(f)=\sup_P\mathrm{V}(f,P).
$$
So (from the definition of the supremum) for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, such that
$$
\mathrm{TV}(f)-\varepsilon\le\mathrm{V}(f,P) \le \mathrm{TV}(f).
$$
In particular for $\varepsilon=1/n$, there exists a partition $Q_n$ of $[a,b]$,
such that
$$
\mathrm{TV}(f)-\frac{1}{n}\le\mathrm{V}(f,Q_n) \le \mathrm{TV}(f).
$$
Let now a new sequence of partitions be defined by
$$
P_n=Q_1\cup Q_2\cup\cdots\cup Q_n.
$$
Clearly $P_n\subset P_{n+1}$ and thus
$$
\mathrm{V}(f,P_n)\le \mathrm{V}(f,P_{n+1}),
$$
i.e., $\{\mathrm{V}(f,P_n)\}$ is increasing, and also
$$
\mathrm{TV}(f)-\frac{1}{n}\le\mathrm{V}(f,Q_n) \le \mathrm{V}(f,P_n) \le \mathrm{TV}(f),
$$
and thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{V}(f,P_n)=\mathrm{TV}(f).  
$$

Comment: Thanks you answer was details and easy to follow . appreciate

Comment: in the case in the question instead of  $\{TV(f,P_n)\}$ if we have $\{V(f,P_n)\}$ what will change in the proof.

Comment: What is exactly the difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. Now I understood  you already used $TV(f,P_n)$ as $V(f,P_n)$ or as a variation of $f$ with respect to the partition  $P$, thanks.